# Select a string from list with a probability

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

I was trying to create a function that returns a random word character (letter) with a given probability. My reference is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_the_first_letters_of_a_word_in_the_English_language) wikipedia page. In the table you can see the letter t has a 16% chance being the first letter. However, the letter x has 0.045% chance. I want to include every letter.

I'm sure that there is a better way than doing this:

```
import random

def selectLetter():
    letters = ['t', 't', (x16000 times), 'o', (x7600 times),... , 'x', (x45 times)]
    random.choice(letters)
```

**Bonus points:** if the code is capable of accepting a set/list (or whatever) of letters and excluding them and adjusting the probabilities accordingly. It's not necessary but it would be great!

How do I create such a function?

Comment: `choices` can take a weight argument https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dweighted+list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns a random letter, weighted according to the first few entries on the Wikipedia page.  You need to complete the letters dictionary (so that the probabilities add up to 1) to make it fully functional.

```
import random
def random_weighted_letter():
    letters = {"a": 0.017,"b": 0.044,"c": 0.052,"d": 0.032,"e": 0.028,"f": 0.04}
    return random.choices(population=list(letters.keys()), weights=letters.values())[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out weighted list:

```
from numpy.random import choice

elements = [1, 2, 3] 
weights = [0.2, 0.1, 0.7]

one = 0
two = 0
three = 0
for i in range(1000):
    num = choice(elements, p=weights)
    if num==1:
        one+=1
    elif num==2:
        two+=1
    else:
        three+=1

print(one,two,three, one/1000, two/1000, three/1000)
```

The output:

```
217 108 675 0.217 0.108 0.675
```

If there was more loops, you might eventually come to the exact probabilities set by weights. Of course replace the list with your letters and weights with probability in range 0-1, sum must be 1 (100%)

You can also feed size to choices, creating a list of desired size of random values with given probabilities:

```
res = choice(elements, p=weights, size=1000)
print(list(res).count(1)) #199 first time, next time 178
```